# Debug: gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

Trying to jointly train a network with two input branch and two output branch. My loss function `HybridLoss` as shown below. I encounter `RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation` in the `loss.backward()` call. I can't seem to find the `inplace` operation which is causing this issue. Also tried with `set_detect_anomaly(True)` but it doesn't provide any further details other than pointing to `loss.backward()`.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

class HybridLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            alpha=0.5,
            beta=0.5,
            gamma=1,
            smooth=1e-16,
            reduction='mean',
            delta=1.0,
            p_factor=0.5,
            i_factor=0.5,
    ):
        super(HybridLoss, self).__init__()
        self.im_criterion = FocalTverskyLoss(
            alpha=alpha,
            beta=beta,
            gamma=gamma,
            smooth=smooth
        )
        self.pc_criterion = PCHuberLoss(
            reduction=reduction,
            delta=delta
        )
        self.p_f = p_factor
        self.i_f = i_factor

    def forward(self, predictions, targets):
        loss_im = self.im_criterion(
            predictions=predictions['label_tensor'],
            targets=targets['label_tensor'],
        )
        if 'label' in predictions.keys():
            loss_pc = self.pc_criterion(
                predictions=predictions['point_tensor'],
                targets=targets['point_tensor']
            )
        else:
            loss_pc = 0
        loss = (self.i_f * loss_im) + (self.p_f * loss_pc)
        return loss

class PCHuberLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, reduction='mean', delta=1.0):
        super(PCHuberLoss, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.HuberLoss(
            reduction=reduction, delta=delta
        )

    def forward(self, predictions, targets):
        return self.net(predictions.F, targets.F)

class FocalTverskyLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, alpha=0.5, beta=0.5, gamma=1, smooth=1e-16):
        super(FocalTverskyLoss, self).__init__()
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.eps = smooth

    def forward(
        self,
        predictions: torch.Tensor,
        targets: torch.Tensor,
    ):
        tversky = tversky_score(
            predictions=predictions,
            targets=targets,
            alpha=self.alpha,
            beta=self.beta,
            eps=self.eps
        )
        focal_tversky = (1 - tversky) ** self.gamma
        return focal_tversky

def tversky_score(
        predictions,
        targets,
        alpha=0.5,
        beta=0.5,
        eps=1e-16
):
    predictions = predictions.view(-1)
    targets = targets.view(-1)

    # True Positives, False Positives & False Negatives
    tp = (predictions * targets).sum()
    fp = ((1 - targets) * predictions).sum()
    fn = (targets * (1 - predictions)).sum()

    tversky = (tp + eps) / ((tp + alpha * fp) + (beta * fn) + eps)
    return tversky
```

My training loop is as follows:

```py
for data_dict in self._generator:
    if self._eval_mode:
        self._model.eval()
    else:
        self._model.train()
    self._optimizer.zero_grad()
    pred = self._model(
        x_a=data_dict['x_point_tensor'],
        x_b=data_dict['image_tensor'],
        vox_res=self._vres,
        pc_flag=True
    )
    im_acc = label_accuracy(
        prediction=pred['label_tensor'],
        target=data_dict['label_tensor']
    )
    im_iou = tversky_score(
        predictions=pred['label_tensor'],
        targets=data_dict['label_tensor']
    )
    pc_mse = pc_mse_metric(
        prediction=pred['point_tensor'],
        target=data_dict['y_point_tensor']
    )
    train_accuracies += im_acc
    train_ious += im_iou
    train_mses += pc_mse
    if not self._eval_mode:
        loss = self._criterion(
            predictions=pred, targets={
                'label_tensor': data_dict['label_tensor'],
                'point_tensor': data_dict['y_point_tensor']
            }
        )
        loss.backward()
        self._optimizer.step()
```

Traceback with `set_detect_anomaly(True)`:

```sh
  File "<path>/main.py", line 74, in <module>
    trainer.train(
  File "<path>/process/trainer.py", line 97, in train
    ae_tr.run()
  File "<path>/process/executer.py", line 56, in run
    pred = self._model(
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/core/ChiCNN.py", line 320, in forward
    a4 = self.istage4(a3)
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/module/blocks.py", line 228, in forward
    out = self.relu(a + b)
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py", line 102, in forward
    return F.relu(input, inplace=self.inplace)
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1296, in relu
    result = torch.relu_(input)
 (function _print_stack)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/main.py", line 74, in <module>
    trainer.train(
  File "<path>/process/trainer.py", line 97, in train
    ae_tr.run()
  File "<path>/process/executer.py", line 85, in run
    loss.backward()
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 255, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "<path>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 147, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [2, 256, 16, 16]], which is output 0 of ReluBackward1, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

Comment: Can you show the training loop with the backward call (where the error was raised)? btw, do you have multiple backward passes?

Comment: @Ivan Edited the post to include training loop. I do not have multiple backward passes.

Comment: Could you also provide the full error trace as well as the code after the backward pass?

Comment: @Ivan added traceback

Comment: You seem to have something running after having done the backward pass. Could you show more code?

Comment: @Ivan That is the entire loop. After coming out of the loop I just print the metrics, and save the model. that's all . ```print(format_metrics(metrics=metrics))
            if self.model_path is not None: <save model code>```

Comment: Can you update with the model definition? Probably the code of `core/ChiCNN.py`

Comment: Based on the stack trace, it seems like the specific relu here `out = self.relu(a + b)` used in `module/blocks.py:L228` is the one defined with `inplace`. But hard to tell without seeing the model source.

Comment: Are you still working on the problem?

Comment: I found the problem. You were right. I used `nn.ReLU(True)` in one place without paying much attention and it costed me 3 days of distress. Thank you @Ivan